# data frame filter only works with multiple for loops and not with list comprehension

Tags: python, pandas, list, loops

I am having to loop through 5 different unique lists and my code is taking way too long using 5 nested for loops. So I condensed my loop down to one line of code using list comprehension. But now I'm getting an error saying it can't find my first iterator when trying to create a new data frame called df_filter. Creating the df_filter data frame works fine when using the 5 for loops but doesn't when using list comprehension. It keeps saying it can't find the first iterator which is 'winning_scenario'. Any ideas how to get this to work with list comprehension? thanks!

```
# Original Iteration Code Using 5 For Loops:
# Starting time before Loop:
t1 = time.time()

# Create unique lists of product, geography, segment, winning scenario type, and size:
p_list = list(df_final3['Product'].unique())
g_list = list(df_final3['Geography'].unique())
ctv_list = list(df_final3['Custom_Type_Value'].unique())
wst_list = list(df_final3['Winning Scenario Type'].unique())
cto_list = list(df_final3['Custom Total Ounce Value'].unique())

# Create Empty Dataframe:
df_final4 = pd.DataFrame()

# Create First Loop:
for winning_scenario in wst_list:
    # Create Second Loop:
    for geography in g_list:
        # Create Third Loop:
        for segment_type in ctv_list:
            # Create Fourth Loop:
            for products in p_list:
                # Create Fifth Loop:
                for sizes in cto_list:
                    # Create Filter of Dataframe:
                    df_filter = df_final3[(df_final3['Winning Scenario Type']==winning_scenario) & (df_final3.Geography==geography) & (df_final3.Custom_Type_Value==segment_type) & (df_final3.Product==products) & (df_final3['Custom Total Ounce Value']==sizes)]


##### New Iteration Code Using List Comprehension:
# Starting time before Loop:
t1 = time.time()

# Create Empty Dataframe:
df_final4 = pd.DataFrame()

# Create Unique Lists of Geography, Product, Custom Type Value, Custom Total Ounce Value, Winning Scenario PED Type:
geo_list2 = list(df_final3['Geography'].unique())
product_list2 = list(df_final3['Product'].unique())
segment_list2 = list(df_final3['Custom_Type_Value'].unique())
size_list2 = list(df_final3['Custom Total Ounce Value'].unique())
scenario_list2 = list(df_final3['Winning Scenario Type'].unique())

# Create Loop:
[(winning_scenario, geography, segment_type, products, sizes) for scenario in scenario_list2 for geography in geo_list2 for segment_type in segment_list2 for products in product_list2 for sizes in size_list2]
# Create Filter of Dataframe:
df_filter = df_final3[(df_final3['Winning Scenario Type']==winning_scenario) & (df_final3.Geography==geography) & (df_final3.Custom_Type_Value==segment_type) & (df_final3.Product==products) & (df_final3['Custom Total Ounce Value']==sizes)]
```

Here is the error I'm getting when trying to use list comprehension
"NameError: name 'winning_scenario' is not defined"

**Edit**: Here is my full code: What I am doing is iterating through based on 5 different unique lists and calculating the price elasticity. Then putting this information into a new data frame called df_final4. My code works, the problem is it taking too long because of having to use 5 for loops. So just trying to find a quicker way or condense this block of code down.

```
# Starting time before Loop:
t1 = time.time()

# Create unique lists of product, geography, segment, winning scenario type, and size:
p_list = list(df_final3['Product'].unique())
g_list = list(df_final3['Geography'].unique())
ctv_list = list(df_final3['Custom_Type_Value'].unique())
wst_list = list(df_final3['Winning Scenario Type'].unique())
cto_list = list(df_final3['Custom Total Ounce Value'].unique())

# Create Empty Dataframe:
df_final4 = pd.DataFrame()

# Create First Loop:
for winning_scenario in wst_list:
    # Create Second Loop:
    for geography in g_list:
        # Create Third Loop:
        for segment_type in ctv_list:
            # Create Fourth Loop:
            for products in p_list:
                # Create Fifth Loop:
                for sizes in cto_list:
                    # Create Filter of Dataframe:
                    df_filter = df_final3[(df_final3['Winning Scenario Type']==winning_scenario) & (df_final3.Geography==geography) & (df_final3.Custom_Type_Value==segment_type) & (df_final3.Product==products) & (df_final3['Custom Total Ounce Value']==sizes)]
                    # Calculate Price Elasticity of Demand:
                    df_filter['ped'] = np.divide(df_filter['Delta_Demand'].values,df_filter['Delta_Price'].values)
                    # Extract Max ped value:
                    df_filter['ped max'] = df_filter.ped.max()
                    # Extract Min ped value:
                    df_filter['ped min'] = df_filter.ped.min()
                    
                    # Save Columns from df_filter that we only want:
                    df_filter = df_filter[['Geography','Manufacturer Name', 'Brand Name', 'Product','Custom_Type_Value','Custom Total Ounce Value', 'Winning Scenario Type','Price', 'Unit_Sales','ped', 'ped max', 'ped min']]
                    
                    # Map values from df_final3 to df_filter:
                    unmatch2 = df_final3[(~df_final3.Geography.isin(df_filter.Geography)) & (~df_final3['Manufacturer Name'].isin(df_filter['Manufacturer Name'])) & (~df_final3['Brand Name'].isin(df_filter['Brand Name'])) & (~df_final3.Product.isin(df_filter.Product)) & (~df_final3.Custom_Type_Value.isin(df_filter.Custom_Type_Value)) &(~df_final3['Winning Scenario Type'].isin(df_filter['Winning Scenario Type'])) & (~df_final3.Price.isin(df_filter.Price)) & (~df_final3.Unit_Sales.isin(df_filter.Unit_Sales))]
        
                    # Concat together:
                    i2 = pd.concat([df_filter, unmatch2],ignore_index=False)
                    df_final4 = pd.concat([df_final4, i2], ignore_index=False)

# Time taken by Loop:
t2 = time.time()
df_final4
print("Time taken by Loop: %.6f" %(t2 - t1))
```

Comment: Just FYI converting this to a list comprehension is unlikely to help a lot with the time. Can you give us sample input and expected output?

Comment: @ tomjn, I posted my full code on the edit. Basically just trying to get that block of code condense down so I don't have to use 5 for loops. It does work already with 5 for loops but takes too long. Thanks

Comment: What would really help would be having some sample input and the expected output ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples))

Comment: Two questions. Have you tried using `groupby`? What is the point of the `umatch2` line?

Answer (score 0):

As tomjn suggested you probably want to use [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html) to calculate your price elasticity for each combination of `Product`, `Geography`, `Custom_Type_Value`, `Winning Scenario Type` and `Custom Total Ounce Value`.

Try something like that :

```py
def calculate_ped(df: pd.DataFrame):
    for _, group in df.groupby(
        [
            "Product",
            "Geography",
            "Custom_Type_Value",
            "Winning Scenario Type",
            "Custom Total Ounce Value",
        ]
    ):
        ped = np.divide(
            group["Delta_Demand"].values,
            group["Delta_Price"].values,
        )
        df.loc[group.index, "ped"] = ped
        df.loc[group.index, "ped min"] = ped.min()
        df.loc[group.index, "ped max"] = ped.max()
    return df

df_final4 = calculate_ped(df_final3)
```